# Creating empty table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to create an empty table, which will be populated by columns much later in a script.

I've tried

```
$command = 
"CREATE TABLE table ()";
```

in my script, but it won't work. It will only work if I put a filler column inside.

```
$command = 
"CREATE TABLE table (
 LameFiller varchar(30)
 )";
```

But I don't like the idea of putting a filler inside. How do I properly create an empty table?

Comment: You can't create a tabel without columns

Comment: Creating a table with no columns is absurd. It is like saying you want to create a space for something in your house without using any room.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you cannot create an empty table.

The best approach at this point isn't then figuring out how to create empty tables, it's not needing to in the first place.

1. Create the table once its structure finalized
   This is the best option.  You really don't want to be inserting data into a table, then altering, then inserting, then altering, etc.  That just screams poor design.  You should be able to come up with your table structure before you ever add data to it.
2. Create the table before the first data entry
   You'll never insert data into a table with no columns (please let me know if you do, because that would be neat and break 2 impossibilities).  As such, create the table when you first need to add data to it.  If you plan on altering the table or adding more columns, I'd advise against this.  Again, that's just poor design.

Answer (score 0):

In some design cases it is necessary to want an empty table. For example, if you are working on a design project where you want people to create their own custom tables within a database. However, it is not possible to create an empty table. The way around this is to find a single column (usually title or name ect.) and send that variable to your php create table function. from there have a add column button that calls a separate php function that adds another column to the database. Tried to keep this as vague as possible to fit multiple scenarios and just cover a core concept to work around the issue.